# Is there a way to get an email from the email app via intent?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I would like to provide the user the option to choose an email from the email app so I could  handle the message body and the attachments, is it possible?

It would be great if we could do that in the same way we do to get an image:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose a picture"), 1);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to provide the user the option to choose an email from the email app so I could handle the message body and the attachments, is it possible?

There is no "the email app" in the Android OS. There are dozens of email applications available pre-installed on Android devices or on the Android Market.

If you are referring to the AOSP email application, then there is no documented and supported API for this application.